# Is it acceptable to pray any number of rakahs in Sunnah prayer?

Tags: salat, sunnah

I am a self-taught Muslim. It is my understanding that the number of rakahs in Sunnah prayer (any Sunnah prayer) should be 2. If you want to pray 4, then you break it up (2 + 2). Even in taraweeh, we break it up into pairs.

But I have been observing people praying 4 rakahs continuously and giving salam in their 4th rakah (like in the sunnah prayer before Zuhr and Asar). Is this also acceptable?

Comment: Yes it's acceptable.

Comment: I think this is the understanding and interpretation of the hanafi school. As often the whole number or better amount of raka'at is mentioned in ahadith but rarely how the Prophet (peace be upon him) used to pray/break them.

Comment: @Atata. Are you saying it is acceptable in Hanafi Madhab?

Comment: @0aslam0 yes it is